# how to parse "" to long("0") in dotnet

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, long-integer

given the following code:

```
string example = "1234";
long parsed_example = long.Parse(example);
Console.Writeline(parsed_example);
# => 1234
```

Works great.

the following example does not:

```
string example = "";
long parsed_example = long.Parse(example);
# [System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
```

However the goal is:

```
string example = "";
if (example == "")
{
    example = "0";
}
long parsed_example = long.Parse(example);
Console.Writeline(parsed_example);
# => 0
```

is there a shorter, apropriate solution? The above code would almost justify a tiny function, Id preferable have a inline solution. Maybe something such as (pseudo code):

```
string example = "";
long parsed_example = example ?? 0, long.Parse(example);
```

Comment: Consider using `long.TryParse(string, out long value)`.

Comment: What should be the result for `example = "A"`?

Comment: `example = "A"` will never happen in my application. Im parsing nullable long fields which I receive in textfrorm through api

Comment: @julianbechtold `will never happen` typically happens 5 by next Tuesday. What's wrong with `example=="" ?? 0:long.Parse(example)` though?

Comment: to echo @PanagiotisKanavos: the fact that it *shouldn't* happen doesn't mean it *won't* - I barely trust the code on the previous/next line; I certainly don't trust an external API, even if (especially if?) I wrote it; even if it *shouldn't* happen, you should have a defined outcome for what to do if (when) it does, ideally with unit tests that validate various garbage inputs

Comment: `long parsed_example = long.Parse(example == "" ? "0" : example);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```cs
long parsed_example = example == "" ? 0 : long.Parse(example);
```

However: don't be obsessed with single-line solutions; a multi-line solution is often more readable and correct. There are no prizes for creating complex code. You may also wish to look at `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, `long.TryParse`, etc. For example:

```cs
long value;
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(example))
{
    // what you want to do with blank/empty values
    value = 42;
}
else if (!long.TryParse(example, out value))
{
    // what you want to do with non-integer values 
   value = 84;
}
```